# Why do I get ".map is not a function" error when trying to map my fetched json?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am very new to NextJS and I'm trying to display flight data I fetched from the skyscanner.net API. However, when I try to use .map on this data I get error ".map is not a function".

My fetch function:

```
async function getFlightListings() {
  var bodyData = {
    query: {
      market: "NL",
      locale: "nl-NL",
      currency: "EUR",
      queryLegs: [
        {
          originPlaceId: {
            iata: "EIN",
          },
          destinationPlaceId: {
            iata: "LIS",
          },
          date: {
            year: 2023,
            month: 6,
            day: 29,
          },
        },
      ],
      adults: 1,
      childrenAges: [],
      cabinClass: "CABIN_CLASS_ECONOMY",
      excludedAgentsIds: [],
      excludedCarriersIds: [],
      includedAgentsIds: [],
      includedCarriersIds: [],
    },
  };

  const res = await fetch(
    "https://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/v3/flights/live/search/create",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "x-api-key": "*********",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyData),
    }
  );

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}
```

My page where I'm trying to map some data:

```
export default async function Home() {
  const flightListings = await getFlightListings();
  console.log(flightListings.content.results.agents);

  return (
    <div className="pt-10">
      <p className="text-xl">Flights</p>
      <div className="pt-2">
        {flightListings.content.results.agents.map((item) => (
          <div>{item.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I'm able to console log for example "flightListings.content.results.agents" and it gives me the following JSON back:

```
{
  vgwl: {
    name: 'Vliegwinkel.nl',
    type: 'AGENT_TYPE_TRAVEL_AGENT',
    imageUrl: 'https://logos.skyscnr.com/images/websites/vgwl.png',
    feedbackCount: 3813,
    rating: 3.71,
    ratingBreakdown: {
      customerService: 0,
      reliablePrices: 0,
      clearExtraFees: 0,
      easeOfBooking: 0,
      other: 0
    },
    isOptimisedForMobile: true
  },
  wizz: {
    name: 'Wizz Air',
    type: 'AGENT_TYPE_AIRLINE',
    imageUrl: 'https://logos.skyscnr.com/images/websites/wizz.png',
    feedbackCount: 609,
    rating: 2.98,
    ratingBreakdown: {
      customerService: 0,
      reliablePrices: 0,
      clearExtraFees: 0,
      easeOfBooking: 0,
      other: 0
    },
    isOptimisedForMobile: true
  }
}
```

But for some reason I can't map this ^

Comment: None of tthis is an array, these are all just objects. Objects don't have a `map` property, arrays do.

Comment: @Cuzy So I should convert it to an array, correct?

Comment: You can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/w86LEm). Does it work for you?

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) out for looping over object in js

Comment: I fixed it by returning Object.values(jsonRes.content.results.agents); in my getFlightListings() function